# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre macro y const en C?

Tags: c

Repasando C, me preguntaba:

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las macro y las const, si en general el propósito de cada una es crear un valor que jamás cambie?

#### Ejemplo del uso de una const:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    const int height = 100; /*constante de tipo entera*/
    const float number = 3.14; /*constante de tipo real*/
    const char letter = 'A'; /*constante de tipo caracter*/
    const char letter_sequence[10] = "ABC"; /*constante de tipo cadena*/
    const char backslash_char = '\?'; /*contante de caracter especial*/
    printf("Valor de la altura :%d \n", height );
    printf("valor del número : %f \n", number );
    printf("valor de la letra : %c \n", letter );
    printf("Valor de la secuencia de letras : %s \n", letter_sequence);
    printf("Valor del caracter de barra invertida : %c \n", backslash_char);
}
```

#### Ejemplo del uso de las macro:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PI 3.1416//Macro
int main(){
    int  x = 10:
    suma = PI + x;

    printf("la suma es %.2f",suma);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías prestar un poco de atención y poner un poco de esmero al momento de publicar, viendo que esté bien formateado el código y tratando de evitar errores de ortografía? Estamos en un sitio con profesionales, y es importante la forma y la estética de las publicaciones.

Comment: [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/19610). El sitio se está empezando a llenar.

Comment: lo siento :( @Mariano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las macros son directivas tratadas por el preprocesador... una macro acaba generando código C legal, que es lo que va a recibir finalmente el compilador.

Es decir, para el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#define NUMERO 5

int main()
{
  printf("%d",NUMERO);
}
```

Al compilador le llegaría lo siguiente:

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d",5);
}
```

En cambio, las constantes son <s>variables</s> elementos que no pueden ver modificado su valor. Es decir, para el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  const int constante = 5;

  printf("%d",constante);
}
```

El compilador tendrá que pasar el valor de `constante` a la función `printf`. Las dos llamadas solo se podrían parecer si el compilador mete alguna optimización que permita eliminar este paso intermedio.

Comment: [Sin mencionar que las `const` tienen un ambito, a diferencia de las `#define`](http://ideone.com/ouenei).

Comment: @NaCl bien visto

Comment: [Adicional, no creo que existan realmente los valores constantes en C...](http://ideone.com/5BeQOl)

Comment: @NaCl Ya, lo escribiste justo cuando estaba publicando el mio :-). Lo elimino.

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudo mucho a entender bien.

Comment: @NaCI realizas asignación entre tipos incompatibles, char constante a puntero a char no constante.

Comment: @NaCI modificar el valor de una variable const es comportamiento indefinido http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576000/in-c-can-a-const-variable-be-modified-via-a-pointer